# try run web-site on ruby on rails and pg

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, pg

i try to run server and see this...

i not ruby programmer, can you help me run this project? it's old project of website

i have 2 directorys and 2 pg dumps.

one of directory name shared, other directory name a time backup 20130130080242

and 2 pg backup 
psql-banner_system_production-2013-09-26--19-00-02-db.dump.gz
and 
psql-iss_production-2013-09-26--19-00-02-db.dump.gz

```
$ rails server
/home/{user}/555666/20130130080242/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.14.0/lib/pg.rb:4:in `require': libruby.so.1.9: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/{user}/555666/20130130080242/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.14.0/lib/pg_ext.so (LoadError)
    from /home/{user}/555666/20130130080242/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.14.0/lib/pg.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /home/{user}/555666/20130130080242/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/{user}/555666/20130130080242/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /home/{user}/555666/20130130080242/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/{user}/555666/20130130080242/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /home/{user}/555666/20130130080242/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

add postgres to your `Gemfile` in root rails directory

```
gem 'pg'
```

After that run from project root command

```
bundle install
```

And run server

```
rails s
```

Comment: gem 'pg' alredy in file.

Comment: bundle install says 
Your bundle is complete!
Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
It was installed into ./vendor/bundle

Comment: try install oldest pg version `gem "pg", "~> 0.12.0"`